# Alerta universal app win 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Preciso de ajuda para emitir um sinal de alerta no aplicativo que estou tentando desenvolver. Inicialmente pensei em mostrar um textblock piscando em vermelho na tela. se alguém tiver outra opção melhor me ajude ou me auxilie no modo que eu pensei.

Comment: O que você já fez até o momento?

Comment: Ate o momento eu não fiz nada. Gostaria da ajuda de vcs para começar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia ser um `Dialog`, `Flyouts`, `Toast Notification` ou até mesmo como você propôs (embora não veja isso desde a época do clipper/msdos). Depende do que ou para o que você está querendo chamar a atenção do usuário.

Segundo a [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/dialogs)

> Use `Dialogs` e `Flyouts` para notificar os usuários de informações
>   importantes, para solicitar confirmação ou informações adicionais
>   antes que uma ação possa ser concluída.

A melhor forma seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fonte:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/dialogs